# Magento 1 had a "reviews detail" page - but Magento 2 doesn't?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

I'm moving from magento 1 to magento 2 and I have noticed that Magento 2 doens't have a "reviews detail" page?

What I mean is that in Magento 1, you could go to the reviews tab and then I just need to click on the review summary (which is a link) and then it takes me to the "review details" page. Which is a page that shows just the single review for the product.

The URL looks like: [website]/review/product/view/id/[review_id]/

Did they get rid of this in Magento 2?
Or is there somewhere I can put in the admin configuration so that I can turn it on?

Thank you.

Comment: No, Actually only  review summary link in the reviews tab was removed in Magento 2, but you can also access the review details page directly by entering the following URL in your web browser as magento 1:

[website]/review/product/view/id/[review_id]/

Comment: Ahuh! Yes you are correct, you can still get to the reviews detail page manually.
Is there a way to make the link clickable like in Magento 1?

Comment: Yeah you can extend the template file for review and add link to that text using this format "[website]/review/product/view/id/[review_id]/".

Comment: Thank you Grazitti - this works well!